# Power BI embedded React-Native

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, powerbi

I'm trying to put a powerbi graph in my application that I'm creating in react native, but I can't make it work, I can only add the iframe, but it's not responding with the screen size, I would like to be able to add it with the "Power -bi-react" however not working, returns error: cannot read property 'getrandomvalues' of undefined, js engine: hermes

import React, {Component, Fragment} from 'react';

import { PowerBIEmbed } from 'powerbi-client-react';
import {models} from 'powerbi-client'

import config from '../powerbi_config.json'

```
  return (
<PowerBIEmbed
    embedConfig = {{
        type: 'report',   // Supported types: report, dashboard, tile, visual and qna
        id: config.reportId,
        embedUrl: config.embedUrl,
        accessToken: config.accessToken,
        tokenType: models.TokenType.Aad,

    }}
    />
);
```

Comment: Power -bi-react is not supporting in React-Native for reference you can check here: https://github.com/microsoft/powerbi-client-react/issues/24

Comment: Use this to integrate graph in React-Native for reference: https://github.com/nnmer/powerbi-embedded-react-native-demo